# Filtering on a aggregate function

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos DB and trying to write a query to filter document by Name and version. I am new to Cosmos and it seems the way I'm doing applies the filter per record versus the results themselves. Can anyone tell me the proper way to accomplish this:

```
select C.*
from c
JOIN (select MAX(c.version) from c where c.name = "test") maxVersion
where  maxVersion = c.version
```

Sample data:

```
[{"name":"test","verson":1}{"name":"test","verson":2}{"name":"test","verson":3}]
```

Results:
I get a record back for each version vs the max version. IE I only should get one record back and it's version number should be 3

Comment: Please show sample data, current output, and desired output, explaining what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this SQL:

```
select c,maxVersion
from c
JOIN (select MAX(c.version) from c where c.name = "test") maxVersion
```

you will get this document:

```
    {
        "c": {
             "id": "1",
             "name": "test",
             "version": 1
         },
         "maxVersion": {
            "$1": 1
         }
    }
    {
        "c": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "test",
            "version": 2
        },
        "maxVersion": {
            "$1": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "c": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "test",
            "version": 3
        },
        "maxVersion": {
            "$1": 3
        }
    }
```

Your maxVerson equals to c.version in each document, so you will get multiple documents not one.

According to your requirement, you can try something like this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM c
WHERE c.name = "test"
ORDER BY c.version DESC
```